# How to calculate exact target value given list of integers

Tags: java

Can someone please guide what wrong I am doing? I have researched a lot in past 4-5 days, everyone keeps on pointing on Subset Sum Problem or Partition problem, For Simplicity Reasons, I have only given the part which is behaving incorrectly.

```
for (Iterator<Activity> iterator = listOfActivities.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Activity currentAct = iterator.next();
    if (time + currentAct.getTime() <= 180) {
        timetable.add(currentAct);
        time += currentAct.getTime();
        iterator.remove(); //removing the current activity once its added to the schedule.
    }
}

time += 60;
timetable.add(new Activity("Eat Food 20min", "20"));
// Post Lunch Activities Start here:
for (Iterator<Activity> iterator = listOfActivities.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    Activity currentAct = iterator.next();
    if (time + currentAct.getTime() >= 240 && time + currentAct.getTime() <= 480) {
        timetable.add(currentAct);
        time += currentAct.getTime();
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what `listOfActivities` contains or what `timetable` is. Please try to create a [mcve]. Not just minimal, but *also* complete.

Comment: It would be more clear if you code provide the code in the question, not as external links. Have you made efforts to step through the code with a debugger and make sure your algorithm makes sense "on paper"?

Comment: If it needs to equal exactly 180, then I can't think of any algorithms outside of linear optimization (which I have not done in Java).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you need to find the subset of numbers of your list that sum up to 180 and then add the corresponding activities to the Pre-lunch list and the rest to the Post-lunch one.

As the retrieving of the corresponding activities is not an issue in this case you might want to look into [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36214/find-all-subsets-of-an-int-array-whose-sums-equal-a-given-target) where an algorithm is described that should be suitable for your problem.
It's a basic numeric approach that tries out all possible combinations and then checks which of them match the needed sum.

Comment: Is it always 5 minutes? Even if you're using different activities with different durations?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid would happen because you only try combinations in order of the list and don't take the necessary step back and try to leave out the first/second/etc activity and try to find a combination with the rest of the activities. Therefore you need to try out all combinations as the linked algorithm does it... And if you simply create an Integer array with all the durations of your activities it shouldn't be too much to implement it the way the link shows ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this input: `60, 60, 45, 30, 30`

You algorithm iterates from start and adds whichever item that fits, so it will will add `60` (120 remains), then `60` (60 remains), then `45` (15 remains). Now it obviously won't be able to fill the remaining 15 minutes and will completely miss the option to add `30` and `30` instead of `45`.

What you describe is indeed an instance of Subset Sum Problem, which is a [NP-complete problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). That basically means (simplifying *a lot* here) that you'll usually have to try all possibilities - there's no direct way to arrive at the solution.

What your code actually does now is it tries only a couple solutions, but misses a lot of them. To fix that in a simple way, you'd have to (once you go through all inputs and fail to fill the 180 exactly), remove the last added input and try without it, etc. But it would be better to study and implement the dynamic programming solution of the Subset Sum Problem as described e.g. on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yet this is one of the problems where you need to know the theory to find an effective solution. So don't expect to find a simple, straightforward solution to your problem. The simplest approach possible here is trying all possible solutions (also called "backtracking") as I as well as others suggested.